# Django : invalid date format with Pandas - \xa0

Tags: python, django, pandas, parsing

I would like to create objects from a CSV file with Django and Pandas.
Everything is fine for FloatFields and CharFields but when I want to add DateFields, Django returns this error: ['The date format of the value "\xa02015/08/03\xa0" is not valid. The correct format is YYYY-MM-DD.']

However, the CSV file proposes this type of data for the columns concerned: '2015/08/03'. There is no space in the data as Django seems to suggest...

here is what I tried in views :

```
class HomeView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
def get(self, request,*args, **kwargs):
    
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    Dossier.objects.filter(user=user).delete()
    csv_file = user.profile.user_data
    
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, encoding = "UTF-8", delimiter=';', decimal=',')
    df = df.round(2)
    row_iter = df.iterrows()
    
    objs = [
    Dossier(

        user = user,
        numero_op = row['N° Dossier'],
        porteur = row['Bénéficiaire'],
        libélé = row['Libellé du dossier'],
        descriptif = row["Résumé de l'opération"],      
        AAP = row["Référence de l'appel à projet"],
        date_dépôt = row["Date Dépôt"],
        date_réception = row["Accusé de réception"],
        montant_CT = row['Coût total en cours'],
        

    )

    for index, row in row_iter

    ]

    Dossier.objects.bulk_create(objs)
```

If I change my Model to CharField, I no longer get an error.
I tried to use the `str.strip()` function:

```
df["Date Dépôt"]=df["Date Dépôt"].str.strip()
```

But without success.

Could someone help me? I could keep the CharField format but it limits the processing of the data I want to propose next.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have some garbage in that file, in particular your date is surrounded by a byte "\xa0" on either side.

In some encodings this byte denotes a "non breaking space", which may be why you're not seeing it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I Will look at it. 